# Java GamePanel not repainting after replacing the GamePanel in the Main class

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

So I'm trying to make a little game, I've been making this for like a day. And I want to make the user able to restart the game when they lose.

I have a Main class that I instantiate the GamePanel in. The GamePanel has a Thread, and a while loop is looping while the Thread is not equals to null.

In the main class after starting the thread, I put a method, called restartGame(more info later) to see if I can restart the game.

My logic is that after making an instance of GamePanel the while loop starts of course, so if the thread stops after gameover, the next line comes in the Main, so it should execute the restartGame method.

In the restartGame method, I replace the existing GamePanel variable with a new GamePanel(), start the thread.

The problem: After restartGame(), it's calculating, I can see the console running, but the repainting does not work. All I see is the previous panels last frame.

What did I do wrong? Why is it not painting?

The Main class script:

public class Main {

```
static GamePanel gamePanel;
static JFrame window = new JFrame();
public static void main(String[] args) {

    
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setTitle("Platformer");
    //window.setUndecorated(true);
    
    gamePanel = new GamePanel();
    window.add(gamePanel);
    
    window.pack();
    //window.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setVisible(true);

    gamePanel.startGameThread();
    gamePanel.run();
    
    restartGame();
    
}

public static void restartGame() {
    System.out.println("GAMEOVER - JÁTÉK RESTART METÓDUS");
    window.remove(gamePanel);
    gamePanel = new GamePanel();
    window.add(gamePanel);
    gamePanel.startGameThread();
    gamePanel.run();
    gamePanel.setVisible(true);
    
    
}
```

}

The GamePanel script:

public GamePanel(){
this.setLayout(null);

```
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenHeight));
    Color bg = Color.decode("#2f2924");
    this.setBackground(bg);
    this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
    this.addKeyListener(keyH);
    this.setFocusable(true);

    scoreText.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    scoreText.setBounds(screenWidth-(100+20), 0+15, 100, 50);
    scoreText.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    scoreText.setForeground(Color.white);
    this.add(scoreText);
    
}
```

```
@Override
    public  void run() {
        
        
        double drawInterval = 1000000000/fps;
        double delta = 0;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long currentTime;
        
        while(gameThread != null) {
            
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (currentTime-lastTime) / drawInterval;
            
            lastTime = currentTime;
            
            if(delta >= 1) {
                
                update();
                repaint();
                delta--;
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

public void update() {

```
    if("die") {
        

        gameOver = true;
        gameThread = null;
        
    }
    
}
System.out.println("[updated]");

    
}
```

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("[rendered]");
        
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
```

}

I deleted what can't be a useful information.

Thank you in advance

tried removing and adding the panel, also repainting after instantiating a new panel.
also tried playing with the .setVisible();

Comment: [mcve] please .. and study the formatting help to format the code properly

Comment: Don't recreate the panel. Instead create a method to reset the data of the panel back to its original state.